# Speeding up conversion of pandas to numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy

I've got a Pandas df of approximately 2.5m rows, with a multi-index of the form:
('assetCode', 'date') and approximately 60 columns.

I'm trying to convert this to a 3D numpy matrix:

```
assetCodes = X_calculated.index.get_level_values(0).unique().sort_values().to_numpy()
dates = X_calculated.index.get_level_values(1).unique().sort_values().to_numpy()
columns = X_calculated.columns.to_numpy()
myData = np.empty((assetCodes.size, dates.size, columns.size))

def updateMatrix(row):
    idx = row.name
    assetLabel = np.searchsorted(assetCodes, idx[0])
    dateLabel = np.where(dates == idx[1])
    myData[assetLabel][dateLabel] = row.to_numpy()

X_calculated.apply(updateMatrix, axis=1)
```

This operation takes a very long time. Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you already have all the combinations of assetCode and date in your dataframe, you can do it whit reshape:

```
# example data
X_calculated = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(36).reshape(9, -1), 
                           index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(101,104),
                                                             range(111,114)],
                                                            names=('assetCode','date')), 
                           columns=list('abcd'))

# get dimensions
nb_asset =  X_calculated.index.get_level_values(0).nunique()
nb_dates = X_calculated.index.get_level_values(1).nunique()
nb_cols = len(X_calculated.columns)

# create myData
myData = X_calculated.sort_index().to_numpy().reshape(nb_asset, nb_dates, nb_cols)
print (myData) #same result than with your code
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]

 [[24 25 26 27]
  [28 29 30 31]
  [32 33 34 35]]]
```

If you have missing combinations, you can use `reindex` before with `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` with `unique` value in both index levels. No need to `sort_index` anymore I think as the new multiIndex is generated sorted

```
assetCodes = X_calculated.index.get_level_values(0).unique().sort_values()
dates = X_calculated.index.get_level_values(1).unique().sort_values()

myData = (X_calculated.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([assetCodes, dates]))
                      .to_numpy()
                      .reshape(len(assetCodes), len(dates), len(X_calculated.columns))
         )
```

Comment: This is really good; thank you! I have only one issue; in this case I have a different number of observations for each assetCode, so I will have to broadcast/fill in `np.nan` for the missing values on the `date` dimension.

What would you suggest in this case? (no need to do it for me, I can probably figure it out if I know which way to go!)

Thanks! :)

Comment: @cjm2671 You can `reindex` with all the combinations, see the edit :)

Comment: @cjm2671 although with already 2.5m rows, this reindex might be slow if you don't have a lot of common dates between assetCodes :(

Comment: It worked! It was almost instantaneous too! Thank you so much, I've spent hours staring at it! :)